# Full System Backup - Good Software

Tags: windows, gratis, backup

I have ordered an external hard-drive in order to perform a full system backup, but I'm not really sure which software I should use in order to do this.

Are there any gratis and full software packages available for download that you guys recommend, because I unfortunately don't have the built in windows backup software on my computer as I assume something went wrong when I was installing the OS.

Comment: This is currently too broad; and hence is no different than the question I linked above. If you put a *lot* of requirements it is probably reopenable.

Comment: Not to be disrespectful but the link you gave me only has one answer and the answer is about a paid backup software which wasn't what i was asking for.

Comment: The problem here is that question is way to broad really.

Comment: @user3417643 Not at all; discussion is good. I was in no way saying that an appropriate answer was on that question. However like that question this is just *too broad*. Yes the free requirement does reduce the number somewhat but it is still too broad.